# Reminder for Outlook Meetings

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

I cannot have Outlook Android app because of the corporate policy (email access only on my work PC). Is there a feature on Outlook 2010 to send reminders about the meetings to a non-corporate (external) email?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following script and it works, as you requested.

- Open Outlook and press Alt+F11.
- Go to `ThisOutlookSession` and paste the following script

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim objMsg As MailItem
  ' create new outgoing message
  Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   ' your reminder notification address
  objMsg.To = "youraddress@wherever.com"
  objMsg.Subject = "Reminder: " & Item.Subject
  ' must handle all 4 types of items that can generate reminders
  Select Case Item.Class
     Case olAppointment '26
        objMsg.Body = _
          "Start: " & Item.Start & vbCrLf & _
          "End: " & Item.End & vbCrLf & _
          "Location: " & Item.Location & vbCrLf & _
          "Details: " & vbCrLf & Item.Body
     Case olContact '40
        objMsg.Body = _
          "Contact: " & Item.FullName & vbCrLf & _
          "Phone: " & Item.BusinessTelephoneNumber & vbCrLf & _
          "Contact Details: " & vbCrLf & Item.Body
      Case olMail '43
        objMsg.Body = _
          "Due: " & Item.FlagDueBy & vbCrLf & _
          "Details: " & vbCrLf & Item.Body
      Case olTask '48
        objMsg.Body = _
          "Start: " & Item.StartDate & vbCrLf & _
          "End: " & Item.DueDate & vbCrLf & _
          "Details: " & vbCrLf & Item.Body
  End Select
  ' send the message 
  objMsg.Send
  Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

- Change `youraddress@wherever.com` with your external email address.
- Save and exit.

---

[Source](http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/sendreminder.htm)